# how to solve dimension mismatch problem in scipy sparse csr matrix

Tags: python, machine-learning, scipy, naivebayes

I've data for training in which the shape of X_train is: (4000, 206908).
But in my test data, the shape of X is: (2500, 48938). That's why I am unable to predict my test data using my trained model. It's showing dimension mismatch.

```
from sklearn import datasets
from joblib import Memory
from sklearn.datasets import load_svmlight_file
mem = Memory("./mycache")

@mem.cache
def get_data():
    data = load_svmlight_file("task_a_labeled_train.tf")
    return data[0], data[1]

X, y = get_data()

from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.naive_bayes import MultinomialNB
from sklearn.metrics import accuracy_score

X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y,test_size = 0.3, random_state=42)
model = MultinomialNB()
model.fit(X_train,y_train)
y_pred = model.predict(X_test)

accuracy_score(y_pred,y_test)

#########################

@mem.cache
def get_data2():
    data = load_svmlight_file("task_a_u00_tune.tf ")
    return data[0], data[1]

X2, y2 = get_data2()

y_pred = model.predict(X2)
# dimension mismatch
```

Comment: Seems like your train and test data are different. If we take the first dimension as the batch size i.e. total number of records, then the next dimension contains the features of each record. Your training data thus has 206908 features while your test data has 48938 features. Thus making the 2 sets of data completely different. You cannot predict on different datasets.

Comment: @mb0850 is it possible to add the missing features (which is present in the first dataset) in the second dataset with value 0 and then predict?

Comment: it is possible to expand dimensions of your data. But just making sure that the shape of the train and test set matches doesn't make them the same thing. You cannot compare apples to oranges, even if you paint the orange red.